# Select from a loop to a list of table that has similar name but with increment numbers added

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to use a query to loop through tables that are similar in  names but added a number after that  (ie. tableJan01, tableJan02, tableJan03, etc..., tableJan30)

Is there a way in  SQL Server to use the same query statement while varying the table name within it. (similar to using parameter values) (need this to add different input to each different month's table)

```
declare @x nvarchar(50) ='abc'
declare @z int =1
while (@z<30)
BEGIN
   SET @z = @z + 1;

   select * from (@x) 
END;
```

this shows error

> Must declare the scalar variable "@CharVariable".

this script shows too  syntax error

```
declare @x nvarchar(50) ='abc'
declare @z int =1
while (@z<30)
BEGIN
   SET @z = @z + 1;

   select * from (@x+@z) 
END;
```

also, simple code like this doesn't work too

```
declare @x nvarchar(50) ='abc'
select * from @x
```

Comment: SQL Server does not support macro substitution ... dynamic SQL would be required.  That said, it still feels like a design flaw.

Comment: if there any code snippet or how to use dynamic sql this would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with John Cappelletti that this requirement feels like a design flaw, however, to get your list of table names you can do something like this:

```
declare @x nvarchar(50) ='abc'
declare @z int =1 
declare @ListOfTableNames TABLE (TableName nvarchar(50));
while (@z<30)
BEGIN
   SET @z = @z + 1;
   INSERT INTO @ListOfTableNames (TableName) VALUES (@x + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), @z))     
END

SELECT * FROM @ListOfTableNames
```

To do dynamic SQL on these tables you could build a query string and then pass that string to the `sp_executesql` proc. You could put that logic in place of the line where we populate the table variable with the numbered table names. Like this:

```
declare @x nvarchar(50) ='abc'
declare @z int =1
declare @sql NVARCHAR(100)
while (@z<30)
BEGIN
   SET @z = @z + 1;
   SET @sql ='SELECT * FROM '+ (@x + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), @z))
   EXEC sp_executesql @sql
END
```

Comment: could you also, please why this is considered as a design flaw and why? - personally I fell the same but I couldn't explain why for other team member and thank you

Comment: Essentially, ABC should be one big table with a column to identify the month. If size/manageability is an issue partitioning a single table may be a reasonable approach.

Answer (score 2):

I would completely avoid a `WHILE` loop just use some pattern matching:

```
DECLARE @Prefix sysname = N'abc';
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

SET @SQL = STUFF((SELECT @CRLF + 
                         N'SELECT *' + @CRLF +
                         --N'       ,N' + QUOTENAME(t.[name],'''') + N' AS TableName' + @CRLF + --Uncomment if wanted
                         N'FROM ' + QUOTENAME(s.[name]) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(t.[name]) + N';'
                  FROM sys.schemas s
                       JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
                  WHERE t.[name] LIKE @Prefix + '%'
                    AND t.[name] NOT LIKE @Prefix + N'%[^0-9]'
                  ORDER BY t.[name]
                  FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,2,N'');
--PRINT @SQL;

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8baec1e8ee2244c46cc9a7e94a2d7ae6)

But John is right, you certainly have a design flaw here.

Comment: could you also, please why this is considered as a design flaw and why? - personally I fell the same but I couldn't explain why for other team member and thank you

Comment: The key thing is that when you have tables like `abcJan1`, `abcJan2`, `abcJan3` then it means that to perform a join to get a row which could be in any of those table (aka dynamically) it is impossible without dynamic SQL. Normally you would build "tall" and have a column that represents the suffix you have for your tables (`'jan1'`,`'jan2'`, etc). Hope that gives some explaination, @user4833581 .

Comment: @larnu depending on the version of SQL server, the [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function might be preferred to the XML/STUFF approach.

Comment: `STRING_AGG` is only in SQL Server 2017+ though, @JoshJay . As a result, as many don't have 2017/2019 I tend to stick to using `FOR XML PATH`.

Comment: @Larnu, thanks for putting in the specific versions. I figured it would be helpful to mention to those who come to this question with a version with it. I've only recently started using it and it is much easier to read and follow.

Comment: Does make me think i should get around to writing an article speed comparison between `STRING_ AGG` and `FOR XML PATH` though. Something to do while at the office and no one else is over Christmas perhaps :/

Answer (score 1):

Using dynamic SQL, it would look something like this:

```
declare 
    @Base_table_name nvarchar(50)  = 'my_table'
   ,@Step            int           = 1
   ,@SQL             nvarchar(max);

while(@Step < 30)
begin
    set @SQL = 'select * from ' + @Base_table_name + right('00' + cast(@Step as nvarchar(50)),2);

    print(@SQL); --this displays the SQL that would be run
    --exec(@SQL) --uncomment this to run the dynamic SQL

    set @Step+=1;
end;
```

Alternatively, you can be more precise by using the sys.schemas and sys.tables tables like so:

```
declare 
    @Base_table_name sysname  = 'my_table'
   ,@schema_name     sysname  = 'my_schema'
   ,@Step            int           = 1
   ,@StepCount       int           = 0
   ,@SQL             nvarchar(max);

/* This will create a table variable and populate it with all the tables you'll want to query */
declare @tables_to_query table (Step int identity, SchemaName sysname, TableName sysname);

insert into @tables_to_query(SchemaName, TableName)
select
    s.name
    ,t.name
from
    sys.schemas s
    inner join
    sys.tables t on s.schema_id = t.schema_id
where
    s.name = @schema_name --this will limit the tables to this schema
    and t.name like @Base_table_name + '%' --this will look for any table that starts with the base table name

/* this loops through all the tables in the table variable */
while(@Step <= @StepCount)
begin
    select
        @SQL = 'select * from ' + quotename(SchemaName) + '.' + quotename(TableName)
    from
        @tables_to_query
    where
        Step = @Step

    print(@SQL); --this displays the SQL that would be run
    --exec(@SQL) --uncomment this to run the dynamic SQL

    set @Step+=1;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

The dynamic SQL approaches laid out in other answers will certainly get the job done for you, but if you find you're querying all of these tables frequently, it might server you well to build out a `VIEW` and query that as needed.

In keeping with Larnu's suggestion of putting the source table name into the result set, I'd probably do something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.vwJan
AS 
SELECT
  'tableJan01' AS SourceTable,
  <Column List>
FROM dbo.tableJan01
UNION ALL
...<28 other iterations>
SELECT
  'tableJan30' AS SourceTable,
  <Column List>
FROM dbo.tableJan30;
```

From there, you can go ahead and query them all to your heart's content with a single statement.

```
SELECT
  SourceTable,
  <Any other columns you're interested in>
FROM
  vwJan;
```

Comment: thanks for your recommendation 
these tables are generated on a daily basis as I have a new table for every day.

Comment: Do the names of the tables change every day?

Comment: yes, an everyday new table with new transactions with a new name depend on the day date

Comment: could you also, please why this is considered as a design flaw and why? - personally I fell the same but I couldn't explain why for other team member and thank you